# In laravel controller How to put two variables together in one function

Tags: laravel, function, variables

I need to put two variables in the same function but i don't know the right way to do it,

```
Public function history($id , $post_id){}
```

It's give me Error

Too few arguments to function
App\Http\Controllers\dashboard\pistController::history(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

In the end
Sorry for bad English

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is this a route that is pointing to this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use your declare function, You must pass values match to your declare function's arguments.

example
If you declare `Public function history($id , $post_id){}`

You must call function with 2 arguments like `history(1, 3);`